# Elastix call-center with computer telephony crm integration

Tags: voip, asterisk, crm

The title isn't explanatory enough but I can't explain it better.

I want to setup a call-center using elastix which would have the following feature:

Suppose bob(client) calls the center and Alice(employee) picks up the phone when that happens I want Bob's client information to appear on Alice's screen and when the call gets forwarded I want Bob's information to also get forwarded.

I know how to do the plain call-forwarding part and I know that the info part needs a Crm to get done(probably sugar or vtiger) but I don't know a thing about crms and I couldn't find any guide containing what I'm looking for online

any help would be appreciated, 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [ADAT - Asterisk Dialing & Announcement Tool](http://www.tttelecom.nl/index.php/en/component/docman/cat_view/11-adat). Someone already posted on Elastix forum on [incoming call popups](http://www.elastix.org/index.php/component/kunena/37-vtiger/94884-better-incoming-call-popups.html?lang=en) with vtiger CRM.

Comment: thanks for the info I'll give it a go, but being a linux fan I'd like something that could work on the few debian-xfce running boxes there are in the call-center as a linux-transition pilot project